# What type to use in useRef of iframe

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iframe

I would like to avoid using a type of `any` and I can't find what type definition am I supposed to use for it:

`const iframe = useRef<any>();`

```
<iframe
    ref={iframe}
    sandbox='allow-scripts'
    srcDoc={rootHtml}
/>
```

So that later Typescript can recognize properties of `iframe.current` such as
`iframe.current.contentWindow` and `iframe.current.srcdoc`,...

*Edit

If I try using `HTMLIFrameElement` as suggested I receive this error under the `ref={iframe}` saying:

> Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLIFrameElement | undefined>' is not >assignable to type 'LegacyRef | undefined'.
> Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLIFrameElement | undefined>' is not >assignable to type 'RefObject'.
> Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
> Type 'HTMLIFrameElement | undefined' is not assignable to type >'HTMLIFrameElement | null'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLIFrameElement | >null'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 4):

i'm very surprised hovering over the iframe ref prop in vscode didnt provide you with the type `HTMLIFrameElement`

EDIT: You will also need to default there to null as the element refs return the type or null and not undefined `const f = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null);`

Comment: @iLijalvic right. thats the default I was talking about. refs return the element or null never undefined. Meanwhile, using `const r = useRef<T>()` has TS typing r.current as T | undefined because the empty () is implied undefined. So, you need to default useREf to null ie `const f = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>(null);` so f.current will match HTMLIFrameElement | null which is what the iframe jsx element expected in it's ref type.

Answer (score 2):

```
const iframe = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLIFrameElement>;
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
const iframe = useRef<HTMLIFrameElement>();
```

You can refer to this file to see other types in the future `@types/react/global.d.ts`